# Site Switcher Text Wrapping/Formatting

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

The text on the site switcher for GIS (Geographic Information Systems) is wrapping to the next line when on that site:
[image]

It does display correctly when on the meta site, however, so the bolded font is probably just barely pushing it to wrap:
[image]

Comment: because when it's weight changed to bold, the container can't accommodate the text

Comment: @redhand Indeed, that's why I pointed out that it doesn't wrap when on meta

Comment: As I pointed in the answer, it is because the first row have to accommodate 3 more links but in meta, it have to accommodate only 1 text

Answer (score 1):

There are few whitespaces before the name. So it splits to next line because the container can't accommodate it completely.

[image]

All the spaces have the effect of one single space. Which means one single space will make it to next line. Because it is on the border.

[image]

Removing the whitespaces will arrange it in one line

[image]

If the devs trim the site name, then it will be aligned perfectly.

This will reduce the distance between the icon and text but it is better than changing the size of container and also better than the 2 line ugly look.

> For meta, it is different. Meta got a lot of space but for the main site, it have to accommodate the site name, *help*, *chat* and *log out* button.

Comment: Even without the whitespace, this would still be an issue with long site names such as [sqa.se]. We will probably end up using css with `overflow: ellipsis;`